# Changing language in Pages on a Mac?

Tags: mac, pages, language

I have a Mac and I'm a Spanish Student. I primarily use Pages in English, but sometimes I work in Spanish and I'd like to have spell check and not have red lines under all my words. I went to system preferences and added Spanish as a second language but that didn't seem to work. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> to open **Spelling and Grammar** and change your language there (or go to `Edit` -> `Spelling and Grammar` -> `Show Spelling and Grammar`).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also can set that specific language box, that Mateusz mentioned ( cmd + : ) to 'automatic'. This works great for me, as I write documents in German, English and Dutch at the same moment. I don't have to adjust every document then :)